# Why isn't obj and mtl file loading their images/textures

Tags: cycles-render-engine, objects, export, import, .fbx

I'm trying to export an fbx file as an obj, and to test whether it work I had to import it, but when I imported it it failed to load the textures. I have looked at all the other questions related to this but none of them seem to help. Thanks in advance.
[image]

[image]

Comment: No, the file I have was already an fbx file and perhaps not made in Blender.

Comment: Please read the information in the linked answer. While the question specifically dealt with exporting an .fbx from Blender, the answer is broadly applicable to any model exchange between 3D software.